# Python regular expression inconsistency

Tags: python, regex

I am getting different results based on whether I precompile a regular expression:

```
>>> re.compile('mr', re.IGNORECASE).sub('', 'Mr Bean')
' Bean'
>>> re.sub('mr', '', 'Mr Bean', re.IGNORECASE)
'Mr Bean'
```

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) says *Some of the functions are simplified versions of the full featured methods for compiled regular expressions.* However it also claims RegexObject.sub() is *Identical to the sub() function*.

So what is going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`re.sub()` can't accept the `re.IGNORECASE`, it appears.

The documentation states:

> `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)`
>
> ```
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
> non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
> replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
> if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
> a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
> a replacement string to be used.
> ```

Using this works in its place, however:

```
re.sub("(?i)mr", "", "Mr Bean")
```

Answer (score 5):

the module level sub() call doesn't accept modifiers at the end.  thats the "count" argument - the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> help(re.sub)
  1 Help on function sub in module re:
  2 
  3 sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
  4     Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
  5     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
  6     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
  7     if a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
  8     a replacement string to be used.
```

There is no function parameter in `re.sub` for regex flags (`IGNORECASE, MULTILINE, DOTALL`) as in `re.compile`.

Alternatives:

```
>>> re.sub("[M|m]r", "", "Mr Bean")
' Bean'

>>> re.sub("(?i)mr", "", "Mr Bean")
' Bean'
```

---

**Edit** Python 3.1 added support for regex flags, [http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html#new-improved-and-deprecated-modules). As of 3.1 the signature of e.g. [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub) looks like:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Python 2.6.4 documentation:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count])
```

re.sub() doesn't take a flag to set the regex mode. If you want re.IGNORECASE, you must use re.compile().sub()